# What is the meaning of this sentence?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Man A is talking to another Man B :

> I might even make it worth your while to talk to me.

sentence is too confusing, My understand: B is telling: there will be useful to A if he tell his words to him(B).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, person A is persuading person B to talk to him(person A). By

> make it worth your while,

person A is hinting at the possible benefits if person B talks to him. For an example, person A could be a wealthy villain and person B could be a policeman. The villain might say such a sentence while trying to bribe the policeman.

The incentive for person B might not necessarily be monetary though- it could be anything that person B benefits from.